# How do I find out the calling class?

Tags: java

how can i find out which class/method has called the actual method?

Comment: If you need to do this for functionality reasons, i.e. you want your method to do one thing if one class called in and another if another class called it - then your class is designed wrong.

Comment: A legitimate use case for this is if you want to create a logger without having to specify the class name in the calling method. Log5j does this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to create an exception to get its stacktrace.

```
Throwable t = new Throwable();
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = t.getStackTrace();
```

Now `stackTraceElement[0]` contains the caller of the current method.

But beware (from [Throwable.getStackTrace()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace())):

> Some virtual machines may, under some
>   circumstances, omit one or more stack
>   frames from the stack trace. In the
>   extreme case, a virtual machine that
>   has no stack trace information
>   concerning this throwable is permitted
>   to return a zero-length array from
>   this method. Generally speaking, the
>   array returned by this method will
>   contain one element for every frame
>   that would be printed by
>   printStackTrace.

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() will do the dirty work of creating a Throwable for you.

Comment: And obtaining the stack trace in Java is an expensive operation. So don't use it every here and there.

Comment: Thread.getStackTrace() doesn't actually create a Throwable, does it? It just invokes the native method "dumpThreads" to get the stack info. Also, this is a bad solution.

Comment: @matt b - in earlier versions of the sun JVM, it used to.

Comment: stackTraceElement[0] contains the class of the current method. stackTraceElement[1] would contain the caller of the current method.

Comment: @matt b: If it is called on the current thread, it creates an Exception and returns its stack trace. Otherwise, it goes to the native method.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way that I've used:

```
StackTraceElement element=Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
String className=element.getClassName();
String methodName=element.getMethodName();
```

[3] is hardcoded because:

[0] is Thread.dumpThreads()

[1] is Thread.getStackTrace()

[2] is the current method

[3] is the one before the current method

Comment: That would seem to have the potential to break if Thread.getStackTrace changes its internal implementation. A more robust way would be to iterate over the elements until you get your class name and then get the class name of the element after that one.

Comment: True, but I only used the code in Eclipse conditional breakpoints. I never considered that someone would use this code as part of any production code. It is just a debugging trick.

Answer (score 1):

A faster but non-portable solution is to use the following.  It does not create a stack trace and just gives you the information you need.  However, not all JVMs will have this and future version of Java might not either.

```
Class callerClass = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(2);
```

Comment: Indeed it works like a charm...and once you started with SUN implementation it's highly improbable that you will move on a different implementation...at least don't use it if you're writing a library...for an application is safe.

Comment: It is possible to write code which calls this methods if it available but calls the generic approach if it not. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can print a stack trace to do this.

If you want to do this dynamically, I'm not really sure if this is possible (aside from printing and parsing a stack trace dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a debugger, or a profiler. Netbeans has both, but a lot of other options exists.

Else, if you can modify the code you can throw a new exception() and have a stacktrace printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

To echo and elaborate on matt b and yishai's comments:

If you are doing this because you are writing a logger or maintaining trace information or some such, okay, cool. I've used stack traces in production code exactly once, and even that was really a debugging issue: We had a problem with database connections not being properly closed, so I modified the "get database connection" function to save the identity of the caller, and then had a periodic sweep to look for dead connections and see where they had been created.

Java's built-in logging function does stack traces so it can write who called the logger to the log file. I worry about the overhead of this as I understand that stack traces are expensive, but whatever.

But if you're doing this because your function is going to behave differently depending on where it was called from, like "if called from class X update customer data else if called from class Y update employee data" or something like that: Really really bad idea. Pass a parameter or write separate functions.